# Angular form reset() doesn't sets controls to empty

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm referring to [Hero guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reset-the-form-flags) passing the object to empty all the fields in the model like this.

```
this.form.reset({
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "bzz",
  "reporter": "" 
});
```

The problem is that it only sets the fields that are non-empty, i.e. *bzz* in the sample above. I've tried with `setValue(...)` but that gave the same effect. Goolearching the issue gave rather nothing other than references to the Hero examples.

I also tried to use the following. Same effect as well.

```
this.form.get("firstName").patchValue("");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you explain more your problem ?

Comment: Ahem... Not sure. I'm sending in the object and it resets the form setting the fields' values as specified **but** only if the value specified isn't an empty string. Then it doesn't set jack and the old value that's supposed to be cleaned up, stays.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/N9vjdZMdFuj5Td8M5bLG?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.

Comment: @JBNizet I can't neither. I'm using custom validators with custom components. It might be something there. I'll keep digging. Or simply reload the page creating the impression that I've solved the problem, hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass an object, and It will set all the form controls to null:

```
this.form.reset();
```

Comment: Two problems. One - the default values need to be set one way or another. Two - only going `this.form.reset()` produces a bunch of validation errors (I have custom components with custom validations). Also, **awesome** nick. A bit offensive to the weak-herted but to me it's beautiful. I'd love to see the recruited who asks for your SO profile, hehe. :)

Comment: I don't understand your problem then. You want to clear the form (like clicking on a reset button or after submitting), don't you?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. The problem is that due to the custom components I've designed, there's something wrong and I get errors. I didn't realize until now.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana, it's probably because your custom validators are expecting a certain value and since the reset() method sets their value to null, it throws an error. For example let's say your validator does some sort of validation on the length of a string: control.value.length. When it gets set to null, it'll throw an error because you can't access properties or call functions on null or undefined. Simply add this at the beginning of your validator function to make sure it actually has a value: if(!control.value) return null;

Comment: I agree. On the other hand, setting an init object with actual values in the `reset(blob)` method seemed to generate errors too. I've tried setting `blob` to so many things but there are form arrays and groups and all kinds of junk, so it got complicated rather quickly. I gave up and went for a reload of the page. Ugly but effective, hehe. I'll give it another whack later, if I find time, though.

Comment: This sets values to null instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.form.reset({
  firstName: {value: '1', disabled: true}
})
```